# Momentum and jet force - velocity of a boat

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum

Since It's my first post, then: Hi everyone c:

Currently I'am learning about momentum and I want to ask am I getting things right? I solved a problem considering this topic, but since it comes from some old lecture notes I don't have solution. And it's marked as a harder problem so I'm not sure about my way of resoning.

The ramjet of a boat exhausts 200kg of water every second giving it velocity of $5 \frac{m}{s}$, describe conservation od momentum for this situation and calculate velocity of a boat five minutes after start of a movement. Boat weight is 200kg. Neglect water resistance.

As for the conservation of momentum since no external forces act on the boat-water system I can say that sum of momentum of the boat and momentum of tye thrusted water is zero. Because when engine is off sum of momentum within the system is zero.
As $p=mv$ i can write $\frac{dp}{dt} = m \frac{dv}{dt}$ for the boat since its mass does not change over time and hence $v\frac{dm}{dt} = 0$. Using similar equation for thrusted water I obtained $\frac{dp}{dt} = v \frac{dm}{dt}$ (now mass change over time but not velocity). This way I calculated acceleration which is constat ($5\frac{m}{s^2}$ if I am correct). 
What bothers me is velocity being as high as 
$ 1500\frac{m}{s}$
Am I getting something wrong or is it just a problem with werid answer?

Thank you for any help.

Btw. Can I somehow see how my post will look before I post it?

Comment: Seems to me the max possible speed of the boat is 5 m/s.

Comment: Ben, can you expalin why do you think so? As I wrote I was able to calculate acceleration and since it is nonzero, velocity will change over time

Comment: Imagine what the boat sees when it’s going 5 m/s: water is coming at it from the front at 5 m/s, and it scoops some of that water up and sends it out the back at 5 m/s—the same speed as all the water it didn’t scoop up. It does not alter the momentum of the water it scoops up. So at that speed, there’s no thrust.

Comment: I see your point but still I want to ask where I do my mistake? Since mass of the boat and velocity of the thrusted water are constat then increase of mass of water must cause increase of the velocity of the boat thats roughly my thaughts leading to acceleration calculations. This argument seems legitimate. And by the way I want to thank you for your help so far c:

Comment: You have defined the speed of the thrusted water relative to the boat. This is a different, non-inertial reference frame. If you want to apply momentum conservation, you must define the velocity of the boat and of the thrusted water in the same reference frame.

Comment: Explicitly: the boat ejects water at 5m/s relative to *itself*, not relative to the world.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I understand now and it answers my question. I'll see how will calculations look a like now.

Comment: Ben I have onw more question which extends this problem. In front of the boat at the distance d in tye middle of the river there is a load. Boat starts its movement from the river bank what should its trajectory look a like to get to the load in the shortest possible time? On the one aide trejectory should be straight line. On the other hand when boat trajectory is straight for too long time it reaches maximum velocity so it should follow some curve like $x^2$ to keep accelerating.

Comment: This sounds like a separate question.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).